# Kotlin: Evaluation of getter-/setter-methods

Tags: kotlin

I've got following example class:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var car = Car("Ford", 50, 8000)
    println(car.vendor)
    println("Speed: ${car.speed}")

    car.speed = 65 // How does it know which setter to invoke?
    println("New speed: ${car.speed}")
}

class Car(vendor: String = "Unknown", speed: Int = 0, price: Int = 0) {
    var vendor = vendor
        get() = field
        set(newVendor: String) {
            field = newVendor
         }

    var speed = speed
        get() = field
        set(speed: Int) {
            field = speed
        }

    var price = price
        get() = field
        set(newPrice: Int) {
            field = price
        }
}
```

When I change the speed-attribute (please see the commented line): **Where does Kotlin know from, which setter-method it has actually to invoke?**

There are two setter-methods within my class (speed, price) which **both** are named "set" and **both** expect an integer-value.

**Is the order, in which the methods are defined, crucial?**

The respective getter-/setter-methods have to be written directly after the attribute-definition? Or does it somehow work differently? If so: How?

**Are the indentations just a covention?** Or are the indentations needed for the compiler?

Answer (score 3):

`car.speed = 65` is called Property-access syntax. It is equivalent to `car.setSpeed(65)`.

You don't have two methods named `set`; you've two mutable properties `speed` and `price` both of type `Int`. They each have corresponding getter and setter methods; in Java Beans convention, the getter for `speed` would be `getSpeed` and the setter `setSpeed(Int)`.

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html for more details.